# Box2dWeb Revolute Joint falling through the ground

Tags: box2d, collision-detection, html5-canvas

I've been gradually trying to get my head round Box2dWeb, once you get your head round the basics it seems to become very rewarding quite quickly which is great. I can simulate the angry birds effect throwing objects across the page and into structures. I've been taking inspiration from Seth Ladd's great box2d tutorials and trying to adapt them so I can build a level editor where I can begin to create mini side scrolling games. BUT..i've fallen at the first hurdle.....

My Revolute Joint is visible in debug (light blue line between the two bodies). However as it drops towards the floor the joint itself seems to carry on falling(off the canvas) when the bodies themselves collide and stop on the ground. Its as if they are actually not associated with each other at all.

Can anybody explain what exactly I'm doing wrong?

You can find a stripped down version at:

www.g-mccann.co.uk/box2d

Feedback is greatly appreciated, I'm learning so be as critical as you like.

Many thanks,
Gary

Edit: 23/05/2012

Just to update I have now sorted the issue, there seemed to be no fixtures attached to any of the bodies. (Thanks iforce2d) I've up'd 1 your comment but can't seem to accept in the normal way I would accept an answer.

Comment: please ask a more specific question

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your response. I can't really be anymore specific. I don't understand why the joints are not working as they appear to display in debug in the correct place but just fall through the ground when the bodies hit the flaw.

Comment: Judging by the fact that none of the bodies in your example behave as if they are joined together, I would guess that the joint is connecting another set of bodies with no fixtures.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved by using CreateJoint function.

I have studied your script, add i found the solution by adding just this line in your init function.

```
box.addRevoluteJoint("wheel3","chassis", {motorSpeed: -2, maxMotorTorque: 10});
```

I hope that this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I looks that your joint is connecting bodies without fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

For making revolute joint, you have to add two body one is static and another is dynamic. dynamic body is attached to the static body at a point using revolute joint and make it rotate or move by applying motorSpeed and maxTorque after enabling enableMotor. For working examples see this game which uses a lot of revolute joints for making it.
http://pixsansar.com/jumping-and-puzzle-ball-level1

Comment: Revolute joins don't have to be one static, they can both be dynamic.